# add static pdf to current generated on the fly pdf, using itext

Tags: pdf, merge, itext, document, writer

I have a problem adding already existed pdf into current pdf I just generated.
I saw PdfCopy but my situation is a little different. I have a pdf on the fly which is generated right now and before sending it out to the client I need to add an existing pdf into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind losing all interactivity that might be present in the existing PDF, you can use `PdfReader` and `PdfImportedPage`. Please start by reading the [documentation](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf), more specifically section 6.2.1 entitled "Importing pages". You can also download the example [ImportingPages1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=110) or take a look at this code snippet:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(existing_pdf);
PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, pagenumber);
document.setPageSize(reader.getPageSize(pagenumber));
document.newPage();
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
canvas.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
```

This snippet is written from memory. You may need to tweak it here and there if it doesn't work immediately.

Comment: Alternatively, serialize the newly generated to memory (`ByteArrayOutputStream`) and read it into a `PdfReader`, and then you can merge using `Pdf*Copy*`...

Comment: @Bruno problem is "existing_pdf" does not exists (it is on the fly). it is just document which is printing into body of response.

Comment: @pmp If existing_pdf doesn't exist, I suggest updating your question where it says "I have a problem adding already existed pdf" and "I need to add an existing pdf into it" because I interpret that sentence as: there is an existing_pdf. In other words: your additional comment contradicts your original question.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie that's right. my bad. title of question is correct but the body is kinda misleading.
My pdf is on the fly and I have it in memory. Now I want to know is it possible to add another pdf (which already existed) to it?

Comment: The answer is still the same: your PDF is created using the document objcet; existing_pdf is the other PDF which already exists. Please explain what you don't understand about the answer, because I still don't understand the question. When you say "is it possible to add another pdf (which already existed)", what do you mean by "which already existed"? Is it a file? Is it a stream of bytes? (Actually that doesn't matter, but maybe you think it does.)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie ok. here is my situation:
I have a url of pdf (which means the actual file is somewhere) and also I just created pdf using itext (mentioning that the pdf will directly write into HttpServletResponse)
Now my question is, is it possible to combine these two before writing pdf into HttpServletResponse?
Thanks

Comment: @BrunoLowagie 
I got what you mean. Please ignore my previous comment.
That solved my problem. Really thanks